# Inserting into a table snowflake with a passed variable

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table which has 3 attributes

ATTRIBUTE DATATYPE FLAG( 0 OR 1)

My stored procedure takes a string of records in the form
"Att1 Datatype1 1, Att2 Datatype2 0, Att3 Datatype3 0...)
so for example a passed string can be
"DATABASE VARCHAR 1, SCHEMA VARCHAR 1, TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP 0"

My code gets the column names of the table and stores it in a string
My code takes the passed string and puts them into array elements seperated by the ,
However the issue arrises when I try to do an insertion into my table
I keep getting the error "invalid Identifier"

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "ADMINDB"."TOOLKIT".ADD_ATTRIBUTES_SESSION_META ("P_ATTRIBUTE_DATATYPE_FLAG" VARCHAR(16777216))
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
COMMENT='Add Attributes to the table SESSION_ATTRIBUTES_META'
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
  var v_list = P_ATTRIBUTE_DATATYPE_FLAG;
  var arr_list = [];
  arr_list = P_ATTRIBUTE_DATATYPE_FLAG.split(',');
  var v_string;
  var arr_col_att = [];
  var v_sqlCode = `SELECT * FROM ` + "ADMINDB" + "." + "TOOLKIT" + "." + "SESSION_ATTRIBUTES_META";
  
    
  try{
    var sqlStmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText :  v_sqlCode});
    var sqlRS = sqlStmt.execute();
  }catch(err){
     errMessage =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;
     errMessage += "\n  Message: " + err.message + v_sqlCode;
     errMessage += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt + v_sqlCode;  
     throw 'Encountered error in executing v_sqlCode. \n' + errMessage;
   }
   
  for (i = 1; i <= sqlStmt.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    arr_col_att.push(sqlStmt.getColumnName(i));
}

     arr_col_att[0] = arr_col_att[0].replace(/\s/g, ',');
    var v_col_att = arr_col_att.toString();
    v_string = arr_list[0].toString();
    v_string = v_string.replace(/\s/g, ',');
    
    v_sqlCode = `INSERT INTO ` + "ADMINDB" + "." + "TOOLKIT" + "." 
+ "SESSION_ATTRIBUTES_META" + `(` + v_col_att + `) VALUES( ` + v_string + `)`;
                
    try{
      var sqlStmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText :  v_sqlCode});
      var sqlRS = sqlStmt.execute();
    }catch(err){
      errMessage =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;
      errMessage += "\n  Message: " + err.message + v_sqlCode;
      errMessage += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt + v_sqlCode;  
      throw 'Encountered error in executing v_sqlCode. \n' + errMessage;
    }   
  return "SUCCESS!";
$$;

CALL "ADMINDB"."TOOLKIT".ADD_ATTRIBUTES_SESSION_META('DATABASE VARCHAR 1,SCHEMA VARCHAR 1,TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP 0');
```

Comment: Check the Query History tab in Snowflake's web UI to see how your insert statement is being sent from the SP. It will help figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: You need quote characters when constructing your SQL statement. You have to split your v_string variable and add single quotes around the first two elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying line 33 and 36, fixes the issue:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "ADMINDB"."TOOLKIT".ADD_ATTRIBUTES_SESSION_META ("P_ATTRIBUTE_DATATYPE_FLAG" VARCHAR(16777216))
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
COMMENT='Add Attributes to the table SESSION_ATTRIBUTES_META'
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
  var v_list = P_ATTRIBUTE_DATATYPE_FLAG;
  var arr_list = [];
  arr_list = P_ATTRIBUTE_DATATYPE_FLAG.split(',');
  var v_string;
  var arr_col_att = [];
  var v_sqlCode = `SELECT * FROM ` + "ADMINDB" + "." + "TOOLKIT" + "." + "SESSION_ATTRIBUTES_META";
  
    
  try{
    var sqlStmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText :  v_sqlCode});
    var sqlRS = sqlStmt.execute();
  }catch(err){
     errMessage =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;
     errMessage += "\n  Message: " + err.message + v_sqlCode;
     errMessage += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt + v_sqlCode;  
     throw 'Encountered error in executing v_sqlCode. \n' + errMessage;
   }
   
  for (i = 1; i <= sqlStmt.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    arr_col_att.push(sqlStmt.getColumnName(i));
}

     arr_col_att[0] = arr_col_att[0].replace(/\s/g, ',');
    var v_col_att = arr_col_att.toString();
    v_string = arr_list[0].toString();
    v_string = v_string.replace(/\s/g, "','" );
    
    v_sqlCode = `INSERT INTO ` + "ADMINDB" + "." + "TOOLKIT" + "." 
+ "SESSION_ATTRIBUTES_META" + `(` + v_col_att + `) VALUES( '` + v_string + `' )`;
                
    try{
      var sqlStmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText :  v_sqlCode});
      var sqlRS = sqlStmt.execute();
    }catch(err){
      errMessage =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;
      errMessage += "\n  Message: " + err.message + v_sqlCode;
      errMessage += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt + v_sqlCode;  
      throw 'Encountered error in executing v_sqlCode. \n' + errMessage;
    }   
  return "SUCCESS!";
$$;

CALL "ADMINDB"."TOOLKIT".ADD_ATTRIBUTES_SESSION_META('DATABASE VARCHAR 1,SCHEMA VARCHAR 1,TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP 0');
```

As far I see, you haven't implemented the process multiple records in the argument for now, but I think you can handle it.

Comment: God bless you, I have been on that syntax error for far to long. I can definitely do the multiple records